# Creating a sliding scale

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to create a sliding scale for a project I'm working on. I have a range of numbers from 13000 to 225400, and I need them to create modifiers for another part of the project between 1 and 3. so 225400=3, 13000=1, 106200=2, etc. I'm trying to figure out an equation where I can plug in the number from the range and get the modifier, but I haven't been able to figure it out. I would be eternally grateful for any help at all, even just pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: shouldn't the modifier be $2$ for 106200? If not, why it's $1.5$?

Comment: You have just described the equation of a line passing through the points $(225400, 3)$ and $(13000, 1)$. Can you handle it from there?

Comment: The problem here is that assigning the modifier $1.5$ to $106200$ does not seem to make any sense, given the rest of the description you have provided, so it is hard to understand what kind of correspondence you have in mind.

Comment: The 1.5 was a mistake on my part. I've fixed it now. And Oiler, thank you. I failed to think of it in a linear sense. I think i can handle it from that.

Comment: Oiler, that did indeed lead me to my answer, thank you again. And again, apologies everyone for my mistake in the original question.